# How do I reverse `String.fromCodePoint`, i.e. convert a string to an array of code points?

Tags: javascript, string, unicode-string, codepoint

`String.fromCodePoint(...[127482, 127480])` gives me a flag of the US ().

How do I turn the flag back to `[127482, 127480]`?

Comment: `Array.from("", (codeUnit) => codeUnit.codePointAt())`? That’s basically the inverse operation…

Comment: @SebastianSimon - I hadn't thought of `Array.from` and its mapping callback, good call, that's got to be the closest inverse. But note that `codeUnit` isn't an accurate name, since it will be a string containing the full Unicode code *point*, not just a code unit.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The method name `codePointAt` always confused me… is a code point the number or the “character” (i.e. a string; or is that a grapheme (cluster) or glyph?)? `codePoint.codePointAt()` sounds like I want to get the code point of the code point, which doesn’t really make sense… or should that be `(string) => string.codePointAt()`?

Comment: @SebastianSimon - You're not alone there. :-) Yes, I'd go with that last one (in fact, I did when I added your approach to the answer below :-D). A code point is a number that uniquely identifies a "character" in the Unicode standard ("character" is very loose there). A code *unit* is a number that may need to be combined with another number to identify a character, depending on the [transformation format](https://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html) being used. The flag in this question is a particularly complicated example because it's a two-codepoint thing that identifies an...

Comment: ...emoji, so I like to use the winking face () as an example instead: It's code point 0x1F609, character [U+1F609](https://util.unicode.org/UnicodeJsps/character.jsp?a=1F609) in the Unicode database. JavaScript strings are effectively UTF-16 (but tolerating broken surrogate pairs), a 16-bit *transformation format* for Unicode where each value fits in 16 bits. Since Unicode is a 21-bit format, that means some "characters" have to use two 16-bit units -- code *units*. In the case of the winking face, those are 0xD83D and 0xDE09 -- a *surrogate pair* that, in UTF-16, combine to give us the...

Comment: ...winking face (). In UTF-8, there could be anywhere from 1 to 4 code units required to make up a code point (for the winking face it's 0xF0 0x9F 0x98 0x89). I have a short-ish blog post about this [here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/01/26/what-is-a-string/), and I also go into it in detail in Chapter 10 of my recent book (links in my profile). (Apologies for comment length!)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [`codePointAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/codePointAt), perhaps using spread (etc.) to convert back to array and then mapping each of them.

```
console.log(theString.codePointAt(0)); // 127482
console.log(theString.codePointAt(2)); // 127480
// Note −−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−−^
// It's 2 because the first code point in the string occupies two code *units*
```

or

```
const array = [...theString].map(s => s.codePointAt(0));
console.log(array); // [127482, 127480]
```

or skipping an interim step as [Sebastian Simon pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67632677/how-do-i-reverse-string-fromcodepoint?noredirect=1#comment119544374_67632677) via [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) and its mapping callback:

```
const array = Array.from(theString, s => s.codePointAt(0));
console.log(array); // [127482, 127480]
```

Example:

```js
const theString = String.fromCodePoint(...[127482, 127480]);

console.log(theString.codePointAt(0)); // 127482
console.log(theString.codePointAt(2)); // 127480

const array = [...theString].map(s => s.codePointAt(0));
console.log(array);  // [127482, 127480]

const array2 = Array.from(theString, s => s.codePointAt(0));
console.log(array2); // [127482, 127480]
```

Spread and `Array.from` both work by using the strings *iterator*, which works by code points, not code units like most string methods do.